# Why does my linked list in shared memory always lead to a segfault?

Tags: c, linked-list, shared-memory

I have the following simple application.  This has been stripped of error handling and such, to be, well, a minimal complete example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

//#define SHM_SIZE 1024  /* make it a 1K shared memory segment */

struct node
{
    int x;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct node *root[argc+1];
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        int i;
        root[0]=  (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
        for (i=0; i<argc-1; i++)
        {
            root[i]->x = (int)(*argv[i+1]-'0');
            //root[i]->next=&root[i]+sizeof(struct node);
            root[i+1]=(struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) ); //Okay, wastes a few ops
            root[i]->next=root[i+1];
        }
        free(root[i]->next);
        root[i]=NULL;
    }

    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    struct node *data;

    key = ftok("test1", 'O');
    shmid = shmget(key, (size_t)(sizeof(struct node)*1000), 0777 | IPC_CREAT);


    data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
    printf("%p", &data);

    if (argc != 1)
    {
        int z=0;
        for (z=0;z<argc-1;z++){
            *(data+sizeof(struct node)*z)=*root[z];
            if (z) (data+sizeof (struct node)*(z-1))->next=(data+sizeof (struct node)*z);
        }
        (data+z)->next=0;

    }

if (argc)
    {
        printf("This is the routine that will retrieve the linked list from shared memory when we are done.");
        struct node *pointer;
        pointer=data;
        printf("%p", data);

        while (pointer->next != 0)
        {
            printf("\n Data: %i",pointer->x);
            pointer=pointer->next;
        }
    }
    /* detach from the segment: */
    if (shmdt(data) == -1)
    {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, whenever I try to access the shared memory from the process that created it, my output looks good.  Every time I open the shared memory from a process that did NOT create it (argc=1) then the program segfaults.  I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why!

Comment: Presumably, the `shmget` call is different in the program that only reads, which is why you should post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We are left guessing what `root` is and where it comes from, etc..

Comment: Ah, fair enough guys, I just though I was doing something stupid enough to be obvious.  Fixed.

Comment: `free(root[i]->next);` frees an uninitialized pointer

Comment: `data+sizeof(struct node)*z` is suspicious. Maybe you meant that line to be `data[z] = *root[z];`. The `data+sizeof` on the next line are probably wrong too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you attach a shared memory segment in a process, it is attached at some address which has no relation to the address in any other process that attaches the shared memory.  So the pointers in the shared memory, while they point at other objects in the shared memory in the original (creating) process's shared memory, do not point at the shared memory in any other process.

The net result -- if you want to store data structures in the shared memory, those data structures can't contain any pointers if you want them to work reasonably.  If you want pointer-like behavior, you instead need to use indexes into the shared momory, possibly as an array.  So you could do something like:

```
struct node {
    int x;     /* value */
    int next;  /* index of the next node */
};


struct node *data = shmat(...);  /* shm was sized for 1000 nodes */

/* link all of the data objects into a linked list, starting from data[0] */
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    data[i].next = i+1;
}
data[999].next = -1;  /* using -1 for "NULL" as 0 is a valid index; */

for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i = data[i].next) {
    /* iterating down the linked list */
    data[i].x = 0;
}
```

Comment: An alternative to indices is to use one main structure for shared memory (which could include other containers), and then use offsets from the base main structure. For the main structure members, you could use a pointer to the structure and then use pointer_to_structure->member.